# Creating a new Ord instance for Lists

Tags: haskell, typeclass, instances

This is my first attempt at creating a custom instance of a class such as Ord.

I've defined a new data structure to represent a list:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Now I want to define a new instance of Ord for List such that List a <= List b implies "the sum of the elements in List a is less than or equal to the sum of the elements in List b"

first of all, is it necessary to define a new "sum" function since the sum defined in Prelude wont work with the new List data type? then, how do I define the new instance of Ord for List?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, this won't work exactly like the normal list instance. The normal instance only depends on the items of the list being orderable themselves; your proposal depends on their being *numbers* (e.g. in the `Num` class) and so is more narrow.

It is necessary to define a new `sum` function. Happily it's very easy to write `sum` as a simple recursive function. (Coincidentally, you can call your function `sum'`, which is pronounced as "sum prime" and by convention means it's a function very similar to `sum`.)

Additionally, the instance would have to depend on the `Num` class as well as the `Ord` class.

Once you have a new `sum` function, you can define an instance something like this:

```
instance (Ord n, Num n) => Ord (List n) where compare = ... 
  -- The definition uses sum'
```

This instance statement can be read as saying that for all types `n`, if `n` is in `Ord` and `Num`, `List n` is in `Ord` where comparisons work as follows. The syntax is very similar to math where `=>` is implication. Hopefully this makes remembering the syntax easier.

You have to give a reasonable definition of `compare`. For reference, `compare a b` works as follows: if `a < b` it returns `LT`, if `a = b` it returns `EQ` and if `a > b` it returns `GT`.

This is an easy function to implement, so I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader. (I've always wanted to say that :P).

Comment: excellent answer, i'd upvote if I could... Haskell is remarkably intuitive once you have the answer in front of you

Answer (score 4):

How about...

```
newtype List a = List [a]
```

This is very common if you want to introduce new, "incompatible" type class instances for a given type (see e.g. `ZipList` or several monoids like `Sum` and `Product`)

Now you can easily reuse the instances for list, and you can use `sum` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing @Tikhon's approach a bit, you could also use `Monoid` instead of `Num` as constraint, where you already have a predefined "sum" with `mconcat` (of course, you still needed `Ord`). This would give you some more types into consideration than just numbers (e.g. `List (List a)`, which you can now easily define recursively)

On the other hand, if you *do* want to use a `Num` as monoid, you have to decide every time for `Sum` or `Product`. It could be argued, that having to write this out explicitly can reduce the shortness and readability, but it's a design choice that depends on what degree of generality you want to have in the end.

Comment: btw, here's [`Data.Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about ..

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
                deriving (Show, Eq)


instance (Ord a, Num a, Eq a) => Ord (List a) where

      -- 2 empty lists

      Empty <= Empty            =   True

      -- 1 empty list and 1 non-empty list

      Cons a b <= Empty         =   False
      Empty <= Cons a b         =   True

      -- 2 non-empty lists

      Cons a b <= Cons c d      =   sumList (Cons a b) <= sumList (Cons c d) 


-- sum all numbers in list

sumList         ::      (Num a) => List a -> a

sumList Empty               =       0
sumList (Cons n rest)       =       n + sumList rest
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

.. or another solution with the sum function in Prelude.

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
                deriving (Show, Eq)


instance (Ord a, Num a, Eq a) => Ord (List a) where

      -- 2 empty lists

      Empty <= Empty            =   True

      -- 1 empty list and 1 non-empty list

      Cons a b <= Empty         =   False
      Empty <= Cons a b         =   True

      -- 2 non-empty lists

      Cons a b <= Cons c d      =   sum (listToList (Cons a b)) 
                                              <= sum (listToList (Cons c d)) 


-- convert new List to old one

listToList      ::      (Num a) => List a -> [a]

listToList Empty                =       []
listToList (Cons a rest)        =       [a] ++ listToList rest
```